# Using same column with different valus in mongodb

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb

Hi I tried to use the same column name more than once in mongoose but it showing different output.Instead of that I need the expected output is there any way to achieve it.Can anyone help me

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('----------------------------------------------', 
{useNewUrlParser:true,useCreateIndex:true,useUnifiedTopology:true})
const wavicle = mongoose.model('Datasetlist',{
  Dataset:[{
    id:Number,
    dataset:String,
    parameter: [{
      Name:String,
      Name:String,
      Name:String,
      Name:String,
      Name:String,
      Name:String
    }]
  }]
})

const me = new wavicle({
  Dataset:[{
    id:1,
    dataset:'Daily Food Report',
    parameter: [{
      Name:'StoreName',
      Name:'Dates',
      Name:'TransDesc',
      Name:'Amount',
      Name:'credit'
    }]
  }]
})

me.save().then(()=>{
console.log(me)
}).catch(()=>{
console.log(error)
})
```

OUTPUT:

```
_id:5f044c0165a79639745ce2a1
Dataset:Array
0:Object
_id:5f044c0165a79639745ce2a2
id:1
dataset:"Daily Food Report"
parameter:Array
0:Object
_id:5f044c0165a79639745ce2a3
Name:"credit"
__v:0
```

But I need the output as

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
dataset:[
{id:1,dataset:'Daily Food Report',parameter: [
{name:'Store Name'},
{name:'Dates'},
{name:'TransDesc'},
{name:'Amount'},
{name:'credit'},
{name:'Total'} 
]
```

Comment: You shouldn't have same column names. have you tried deleting one of them?

Comment: I need to insert many values for the column name is it possible ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 issues here:

1. The schema definition: Although it actually works the way you define multiple keys with the same name, but at the end the keys will overwrite each others and you end up with an object of only one key. The way to do is as follows:

```
{
  Dataset:[{
    id:Number,
    dataset:String,
    parameter: [{
      Name: String // be carful with the case, your expect the output to have the key "name", but you defined as "Name", the keys are case sensitive
    }]
  }]
}
```

2. Document creation: as mentioned in the first issue. If you define multiple keys with the same name, they will overwrite each others, then you probably end up with a single object in an array like this: `parameters: [{ Name:'credit' }]`. The correct way is to write separate objects

```
const me = new wavicle({
  Dataset:[{
    id:1,
    dataset:'Daily Food Report',
    parameter: [{
      Name:'StoreName'
    },{
      Name:'Dates'
    },{   
      Name:'TransDesc'
    },{
      Name:'Amount'
    },{
      Name:'credit'
    }]
  }]
})
```

3. The logging: when you do `console.log(me)`. It's possible that it won't print all nested structures, So all you see is `Array` while there are nested objects inside. You should do the following instead

```
console.dir(me, { depth: null })
```